# Why is my list of Tuples vertical?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I believe I've made an error in my coding in where my list of tuples prints out vertically instead of the correct way. May someone please tell me what's up?

This is the question being asked:
Enumerate It!
Write a function called enum that takes a sequence and returns a list of 2-tuples with each tuple holding the index and its associated item.

This is the example given:

```
>>> enum([45,67,23,34,88,12,90])
[(0, 45), (1, 67), (2, 23), (3, 34), (4, 88), (5, 12), (6, 90)]

>> enum('hello')
[(0, 'h'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), (3, 'l'), (4, 'o')]
```

This is my code:

```
def enum(aSequence):
    for i in range(7):
        b=aSequence[i]
        a= [i]
        list1 = [a,b]
       print (list1)


If following the example input is used this is the result:
[[0], 45]
[[1], 67]
[[2], 23]
[[3], 34]
[[4], 88]
[[5], 12]
[[6], 90]
```

The result I would desire is:
[(0, 45), (1, 67), (2, 23), (3, 34), (4, 88), (5, 12), (6, 90)]

When I take away print(list1) and use return list1 instead this is the result.

```
[[0], 13]
```

Why is this the case?

When I put this into the website in which I'm being tutored on, the word "Jack and Jane" is displayed and random numbers are shown if a different test. My second question is how do I get the range loop to fit based on the parameter input. I tried to import math and import random. While both are short term solutions they aren't long term solutions.

I feel like I'm overthinking the problem as the code is there just the basic fundamentals might be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks you to *return* a list with the desired structure, so be careful about that. You are just printing one right now.

```
def enum(aSequence):
    list1 = []
    for i in range(len(aSequence)):
        b = aSequence[i]
        a = i
        # use append to keep your items in the list to be returned
        list1.append((a, b))
    return list1

print(enum('hello')) # this should print horizontally like you asked.
```

Regarding the simplest answer to create the list you want, the enumerate function is your friend. The enumerate function unpacks a tuple of the index and the object found at the index for an iterable.

```
thing = 'hello there!'

#typical use case for enumerate
for i, item in enumerate(thing):
    print(i, item)
```

So here's an example function that does what you want...

```
def enum(iterable):
    # must use list() to cast it as an object or else we return a generator object
    return list(enumerate(iterable))

enum('hello there!')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to print everything in the same line

```
 for i in range(len(aSequence)):
     b=aSequence[i]
     a= i
    list1 = [a,b]
    print (list1,end=' ')
```

Since you wanted the result

> [(0, 45), (1, 67), (2, 23), (3, 34), (4, 88), (5, 12), (6, 90)]

Comment: This will work only with python3 (unless print function is imported from __future__), and he didn't specify the version.

Comment: @Nf4r, oh ok I assumed it to be python3

Answer (score 2):

You are almost correct. The problem is with your `a=[i]`. By using `[]` brackets you are creating a list, so `a` is a list, instead of an int. 
Change `a=i` and it will be fine. Also hardcoded `range(7)` should be changed to `range(len(aSequence))`. The ideal solution for you would be something like:

```
def enum(aSequence):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(aSequence)):
        result.append((i, aSequence[i])) 
    return result
```

What you need to remember is the fact, that `print` is not a `return`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should be. You need to create the list before starting the loop.Just like below

```
    def enum(aSequence):
    list1 = []
    for i in range(len(aSequence)):
        b = aSequence[i]
        a = i
        list1.append((a,b))
    print list1

enum([45,67,23,34,88,12,90])
```